# How to bind data to multiple elements using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I need to implement one-way data binding in multiple places using a JSON object.
Below is the JSON object getting from the server every 10 sec, with the latest status of a user.

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<ul>
  <li>User0: <span class="change_status" unique_id="7150032">Busy</span></li>
  <li>User1: <span class="change_status" unique_id="7150031">Offline</span></li>
  <li>User2: <span class="change_status" unique_id="7150030">Online</span></li>
</ul>
<div class="profile">
  <div class="profileimage">
  U
  </div>
  Status: <span class="change_status" unique_id="7150032">Busy</span>
</div>

<script>
function Binding(b) {
    _this = this
    this.elementBindings = []
    this.value = b.object['unique_id']
    this.valueGetter = function(){
        return _this.value;
    }
    this.valueSetter = function(val){
        _this.value = val
        for (var i = 0; i < _this.elementBindings.length; i++) {
            var binding=_this.elementBindings[i]
            binding.element[binding.attribute] = val
        }
    }
    this.addBinding = function(element, unique_id){
        var binding = {
            element: element,
            unique_id: unique_id
        }

        this.elementBindings.push(binding)
        element['innerText'] = _this.value
        return _this
    }

    Object.defineProperty(b.object, b.property, {
        get: this.valueGetter,
        set: this.valueSetter
    }); 

    b.object[b.property] = this.value;
}

obj =  [
  {
    "unique_id": "7150032",
    "status_name": "Busy"
  },
  {
    "unique_id": "7150031",
    "status_name": "Offline"
  },
  {
    "unique_id": "7150030",
    "status_name": "Online",
  }
]

var changeStatusElements = document.getElementsByClassName("change_status")
var binding = new Binding({
    object: obj
  })
for(var i=0; i< changeStatusElements.length; i++){
    var unique_id = changeStatusElements[i]['unique_id']
  binding.addBinding(changeStatusElements[i], unique_id)
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

These statuses will change based on the new JSON that has new statuses. Please assume the JSON (contains a live status of the users) will change every 10 sec.

Please correct my code that would be appreciated.

Comment: No one will share you a code. You have to show your attempts.

Comment: You can write your code in OOPS or in a functional way, in just a way whenever your data changes your view will subscribe it and make the changes in the UI.

Comment: Why do all `<span>` elements have the same unique_id but different status? Also, `unique_id` is your own attribute, so you should make it a data attribute `data-unique_id`

Comment: Save "data" in a variable and then execute loop on that variable to render markup in your "view"

Comment: Please do not link to your code. Embed it into your question.

Comment: Your code does not show where the ajax request is made and where it repeats. Are you thinking to create a new instance of Binding every 10 seconds? I fail to see how creating a constructor is helping with anything.

Answer (score 0):

Give your `ul` element an id attribute, so you can reference it from code. I will assume it is called "container". Initially it should just be an empty element, like

```
<ul id="container"></ul>
```

You should also have a URL where to make the request to. I'll assume you have that in a variable `url`.

Then, you can add this code:

```
(async function request() {
    let response = await fetch(url);
    let { data } = await response.json();
    document.querySelector("#container").innerHTML = data.map(({ unique_id, status_name }, i) =>
        `<li>User${i}: <span class="change_status" unique_id="${unique_id}">${status_name}</span></li>`).join("\n");
    setTimeout(request, 10000);
})();
```

Comment: I have added my code in the question as you said. thank you

Answer (score -1):

I have done this. Please check the following code

```
function Binding(b) {
    _this = this
    this.statusArrProxy = b[b.property]
    this.statusGetter = function () {
        return _this.statusArrProxy;
    }
    this.statusSetter = function (arr) {
        _this.statusArrProxy = arr
        arr.forEach(a => {
            var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.change_status[' + b.key + '="' + a[b.key] + '"]')
            elements.forEach(node => node[b.attribute] = a[b.value])
        })
    }
    Object.defineProperty(b, b.property, {
        get: this.statusGetter,
        set: this.statusSetter
    })
    b[b.property] = this.statusArrProxy
}

var statusArray = [{ unique_id: 123, status: 'Busy' }, { unique_id: 1234, status: 'Available' }]
var bindingObj = {
    statusArray: statusArray,
    attribute: 'innerHTML',
    property: 'statusArray',
    key: 'unique_id',
    value: 'status'
}
new Binding(bindingObj)
//replace the entire array bindingObj.statusArray = [{ unique_id: 123, status: 'Offline' }, { unique_id: 1234, status: 'Out Of Office' }]
```

thank you for all support

Comment: Is this a question or an answer?

Comment: This is the answer. Just assume that "obj" values are replaced with the same reference after API call.

Comment: So what if the number of items in the response is not the same as the number of items in your document? And why use a constructor when you never maintain a reference to the created instance? Why all these methods which you never call (and never *can* call, since you don't have the reference)? Does not look the right way to do this...

Comment: By the way, the methods on `this` (which you never call), are *overwritten* in each iteration of the `forEach` loop. The methods on the `o` objects do not do what you expect, even if you called them.

Comment: I have simplified the code. No need to iterate the objects. You can replace the entire array which you will get from API on the current array.